# Someone with <2000 rep edited my answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

A few hours ago, [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100957/heiko-rupp) with reputation < 2000 edited [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918781/why-does-asynctask-run-in-the-main-thread-of-an-application#4918811). I don't object to the changes he made, but I thought that the privilege of editing questions and answers kicks in at 2000 rep. How did this happen?

Comment: All users can now suggest edits.  Those with under 2k rep go into an approval queue, and 2k rep users can approve those edits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please see the blog post [Suggested Edits and Edit Review](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/).

Comment: Thanks. That clears things up nicely.